# Injective $C^1$ curve $[0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $c([0,1))=S^1$ and $c'$ has exactly 7 zeros

Tags: differential-geometry, polynomials

This is an exercise for the reader from my differential geometry course:

Find an injective $C^1$ curve $c:[0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that its image is the unit circle and its derivative has exactly 7 zeros. Does this work with $C^\infty$ curves?

For the first part of the question, I think it's enough to find a monotonously increasing function $\phi:[0,1)\rightarrow [0,2\pi)$ and then plug that in to the usual $(cos(\phi(t)),sin(\phi(t)))$. I don't know how to get $\phi'$ to have exactly $7$ zeros though. The obvious choice would be a degree $7$ polynomial, but at the same time $\phi'\ge 0$ must hold.

Because this is just a "little" exercise, I feel I'm missing something much simpler. Also, what I've got so far doesn't really help with the second part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to both parts of the question.
$$\phi(t) = \frac {\sin(14\pi t)}{14\pi}+t$$
Then $(\cos(2\pi \phi(t)), \sin(2\pi \phi(t)))$ satisfies the requirement and is obviously smooth, i.e., $C^\infty$